# React Native Navigator : Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: react-native, navigator, react-native-navigation

the error which is shown in the title gets displayed when I try to load a new `Component` through the `Navigator` component.

My View with the Navigator component looks as following:

```js
render(){
    return(
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'Feed', component: Feed}}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
            if(route.component){
              return React.createElement(route.component, {navigator, ...this.props})
            }
          }
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The initialRoute renders the correct View perfectly.
The child Component `Feed` that gets rendered contains a list of Buttons which update the Navigator and cause it to render a new component as following:

```js
  updateRoute(route){
    this.props.globalNavigator(route)
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: route.displayLabel,
      component: route.label
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.bottomNavSection}>
        {
          this.state.navItems.map((n, idx) => {
            return(
              <TouchableHighlight
                key={idx}
                style={this.itemStyle(n.label, 'button')}
                onPress={this.updateRoute.bind(this, n)}
              >
                <Text
                  style={this.itemStyle(n.label, 'text')}
                >
                  {n.displayLabel}
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Note that the `function updateRoute(route)` receives the name of the new component as following: `onPress={this.updateRoute.bind(this, n)}`. Where `n` equals to `{displayLabel: 'Start', label: 'Feed', icon: ''},` for example.

**Edit**
Content of my Profil.js Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactNative from 'react-native'
import API from '../lib/api'

import BottomNavigation from '../components/BottomNavigation'

const {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
} = ReactNative

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Profil extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.scene}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollSection}>
          <Text>Profil</Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <BottomNavigation {...this.props} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scene: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f0f0f',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  scrollSection: {
    flex: .8
  }
})

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    globalRoute: state.setGlobalNavigator.route
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that `onPress={this.updateRoute.bind(this, n)}` wasn't containing the proper component reference but instead was containing the component name as String.

Fixed it by altering the function :

```
 updateRoute(route){
    this.props.globalNavigator(route)
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: route.displayLabel,
      component: route.component
    })
  }
```

and enhancing the state with the component reference and importing the component in the beginning of the document.

```
this.state = { 
   navItems: [
      {displayLabel: 'Start', label: 'Feed', icon: start, component: Feed},
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to export your component.

Comment: Which component? Profil? Profil has the export statement on the bottom